# pboard types will be deprecated

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, deprecated, uti

According to NSPasteboard.h (line 294 in the standard Snow Leopard copy of the Xcode SDK) it states:

```
/* Use of pboard types should be replaced with use of UTIs.
Pboard types will be deprecated in a future release. */
```

I've tried finding samples of using UTIs as a replacement for pboard types but I can't find anything anywhere that demonstrates how to do this.

Does anyone have any sample code showing how to replace pboard types with UTIs?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use UTIs where previously you would have used pboard types.

For more on UTIs, see [Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/).

Comment: I think this is the new link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
[self.tableView registerForDraggedTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText]];
```

Take a look at UTCoreTypes.h